# CreateViewNavFromCategory (lotuscript) ignore next subcategory if the user doesn't have right to view the first?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

Please see the following question, do I make something wrong or is it a bug ? Is there a work around ?

I'm using:
 Set notesViewNavigator = notesView.CreateViewNavFromCategory( category$ [ , cacheSize& ] )

I have a View with 2 categorized columns:

- AAA

  - 111

    > doc1 READER=david
    >
    > doc2 READER=david
  - 222

    > doc3 READER=john
    >
    > doc4 READER=john
- BBB

If david make Set nav = view.CreateViewNavFromCategory("AAA"), nav.count=2==> this is OK

If john make Set nav = view.CreateViewNavFromCategory("AAA"), **nav.count=0** ==> WHY ???

if the admin (can see all docs) make Set nav = view.CreateViewNavFromCategory("AAA"), nav.count=4 => it proves the 2nd sub category is "read" by notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the view- Property "Do not display empty categories": It should make the result more reasonable. I can not explain, why the nav.count is 0 but in my experience e.g. a dblookup only takes the first sub- category and ignores the documents in the second category under some circumstances.

If you find out, that the second category column "disturbs" your code, then simply try to make the second column sort only instead of categorized (of course only if this fits your needs).

Comment: Thanks for your response, "Don't show empty categories" already checked.

Comment: I'm almost sure that your idea of making the 2nd col NOT categorized will solve the problem, but This second category is necessary (some users see more than 1 category and need to see this with twistie).

Comment: If you need this for the users: Why don't you create a new view just for "programmatic" use? This for sure is best practice: keep "Frontend" (what users see) and "backend" (what your script needs) apart from each other, otherwise you will mess up your code whenever users want to see something different in "their" view... That's what hidden views are made for...